# Check if request is a direct user initiated request or a browser initiated request

Tags: php, request

Is there a way to check with PHP if the current request is a direct request that was explicitly triggered by the user (for example by opening http://myhost.local/test in browser) or if it is a request that was triggered by the browser it's self through for example script or link references within the markup?

I think the HTTP_REFERER var is not a good option. Sometimes it is not set by the browser and there are no points that would enable me to use the var to determine the source of the request.
Settings query parameter to assets that could fail to load as a marker is also no satisfying option - its to error-prone. Also identifying direct and indirect requests by the path they are (or should be) places in is not a clean and elegant solution I think.

**The Problem:**
We got a company's internal framework for static webpages. This framework uses a php router in order to obtain nice smart-urls.
Requests are automatically checked against page-files on the filesystem and if there is no file for the request, the user is shown a custom 404 page coming through a php-file within the project.

And this is where the problem kicks in: A user who requests anything that does not exist would be shown the custom 404 page - that's perfectly fine. But this should not happen if the browser it self (instead of the user) requests a resources (like images, javascript or css-files), because this would cause the whole framework to boot up with all the modules just to send out the custom 404 pages to the browser background/nirvana. This slows page loading down massively if assets do not exist - especially if there are multiple assets that do not exist.

I know that the case of in-existing assets should not even happen, but while building the pages it happens from time to time that something is missing and I just want the framework to be cleaner and speed things up a bit - so anyway I just want the framework to differentiate between direct and indirect requests.

Comment: You should probably be looking at the `Accept` HTTP request headers as the main differentiator. But if this is merely a performance optimisation, I'd rather solve this through caching in the web server or a CDN of some sort. Yes, the first hit to a 404 URL will still trigger the framework to be spun up, but once that happened once the 404 page can be cached and reused.

Comment: Using the Accept-Header is an awesome advice! I think this may take me further - gonna check that. Thank you very much! And thanks for the notes on perhaps following a complete wrong concept leading me to this issue. Thanks!